# Can information leak through between merging black holes during the merger?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, information

There are other questions on this site about black hole mergers and information, but none of them answer my question.

[What happens to information when black holes merge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20690/)

This does not give a satisfactory answer to my specific question.

> This means that $dr/dt$ cannot change sign once $r<r_s$. Thus once moving into a black hole ($dr <0$), then the radial coordinate cannot increase.

[Why radial coordinate of a particle must decrease continuously once it is inside the Schwarzschild radius?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494149/)

> Nothing can remain stationary and the decrease in the radial coordinate is as inevitable as the increase of the temporal Can information leak through between merging black holes during the merger? merging black holes, there is a period when there seems to be a "tunnel" between the two holes, and the event horizons seem to be connected.

[Does anything exist between singularity and the event horizon of a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241632/)

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ

Based on this animation video, there is a period of time where there is a connection between the two event horizons (seems like a "tunnel" between them), so the two black holes seem to be connected.

Now I believe the answer to my question is not trivial, because if EM waves (and information) can only travel along a trajectory that has a decreasing radial coordinate, then it is questionable whether information can leak through that "tunnel" during the merger.

So basically, does the information content of the black holes gradually leak to the other one during the merger (in some way, for example through that "tunnel"), or are they completely separate, and all the information "merges" in one step as the two black holes complete the merger? I would naively say that it is the former, and information has to leak gradually during the merger, but then it has to be done through that "tunnel", where the two black holes open up, and I do not know whether this animation is accurate.

Question:

1. Can information leak through between merging black holes during the merger?

Comment: Unfortunately, those equations only apply to a single, static, black hole, with nothing else in the universe.  There are currently _no_ closed form equations for more than one massive body in General Relativity.  The only way to model this scenario is with Numerical Relativity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_relativity, but that is a very general and extremely complicated technique, and there is no simple quantity like $r _ s$ to play with.